# spark how can I split rdd by key to multiRDD for kmeans

Tags: apache-spark-mllib

I have a huge data, I load it to rdd,
I want to kmeans for data by category ,so I transformate rdd:

```
[String] to rdd1:[(String,List[String])]

val dataRdd = sc.textFile(path)
val rdd1[(String,List[String])] = dataRdd.map(....)
```

I know we can't create nested rdd ,so I can I split rdd1 to multirdds for kmeans?

this is the data file , I want to kmeans by category(A,B,C) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDz2F.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split your data to train and test your kmeans model, you can use:

```
// Load and parse the data file.
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")
// Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))
```

But the question is not so clear....

Comment: just I have 3 category data in a file , I want to kmeans for each category at the same time ,but I don't know  how can I do